# How is an Android activity instantiated (using reflection)?

Tags: java, android, reflection

Got asked this today in an Android interview. I answered the usual, you know, intent + startActivity, etc. Interviewer then asked more pointedly,

> "Yes, but where is it actually *instantiated*? You don't call new
>   Activity anywhere".

Which now that I think about it, I don't really know. He hinted that it used Java reflection, but I dont have a lot of experience with that, and I've only used it to access some variables in the Android SDK.

Can someone explain how Activities are instantiated using reflection, and *why*? Bonus points for insight into what value the interviewer saw in knowing this.

Comment: I think the value for the interviewer is that he can see that you not only can use the framework, but also have interest in why and where all the stuff happens. But even if you haven't checked it yet, your reaction to such unexpected questions shows the interviewer how you can cope with unexpected situations and how fast you can come up with a possible answer.

Answer (score 27):

When an app's launcher icon is clicked on homescreen, following event happens under the android system  :

> - Homescreen/Launcher app sends an intent to start an activity using    startActivity()(startActivity() is binder call to ActivityManager)
> - Activity Manager sends a process fork request using a socket to    Zygote.
> - Zygote forks a new VM instance that loads ActivityThread(Activity thread manages the execution of the main thread in an application process, scheduling and executing activities, broadcasts, and other operations on it as the activity manager requests.).
> - ActivityThread has real main() for an app.
> - ActivityThread calls the    app's onCreate().

***Hence ActivityThread is responsible for instantiating Activity(inside performLaunchActivity method)***

Explanation :

If you observe the stacktrace :

```
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
```

Code where new activity is instantiated :

```
private Activity performLaunchActivity(ActivityClientRecord r, Intent customIntent) {
    ... //More code
    Activity activity = null;
    try {
        java.lang.ClassLoader cl = r.packageInfo.getClassLoader();
        activity = mInstrumentation.newActivity(
                cl, component.getClassName(), r.intent);
        StrictMode.incrementExpectedActivityCount(activity.getClass());
        r.intent.setExtrasClassLoader(cl);
        r.intent.prepareToEnterProcess();
        if (r.state != null) {
            r.state.setClassLoader(cl);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!mInstrumentation.onException(activity, e)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Unable to instantiate activity " + component
                + ": " + e.toString(), e);
        }
    }
    ... //More code
    return activity;
}
```

Instrumentation.java(class will be instantiated for you before any of the application code)

```
public Activity newActivity(ClassLoader cl, String className,
        Intent intent)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    return (Activity)cl.loadClass(className).newInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to check the path to the constructor method is to create a temporary project, override constructor in your `Activity` and place breakpoint there.

You should be able to walk through the all code and find what exactly you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are not in an interview for an Android system developer (kernel hacker, ...) the answer is simply: That is an implementation detail of the Android framework a normal Android developer should not need to care about because of the abstraction and layer principle and it can be looked up in the rare case you would really need to know it.

Answer (score 0):

Android core is responsible to manage de activity instantiation, and manage it into his activity lifecycle.

The android system takes care about calling all the events you can control in your class in the correct order, add the activity to the stack and many other things.

When you call startActivity, Android core takes control and makes an activity instance (or reuse a previous one if match) and starts to call activity lifecycle events

You can see it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html in Activity Lifecycle part